# Is chrome flagging all calls to servers without SSL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I am using geonames.org to auto populate my address fields based on zip code. I have been using there api and it was woking recently when I saw the following error:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

This is the bit of code i'm using to make the api call:

```
   $.getJSON("https://www.api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=" + zip[0] + "&country=" + country + "&username=myUsername", function(response) {

            //code for my view          
            $(".locked").attr("readonly", false);

            var places = response.postalcodes;

            if (places.length > 1){
                $.each(places, function(i, place) {
                    $('#rightSideZip').append('<li class="zipLookups" data-city="' + place.placeName + '" data-zip="' + place.postalcode + '" data-state="' + place.adminCode1 + '"><span>' + place.postalcode + ' – ' + place.placeName + '</span><p>' + place.adminName1 + '</p></li>')});
                } else {
                    city.val(response.postalcodes[0].placeName).blur();
                    state.val(response.postalcodes[0].adminCode1).blur();
                    lat.val(response.postalcodes[0].lat).blur();;
                    lng.val(response.postalcodes[0].lng).blur();;

                    latitude = response.postalcodes[0].lat;
                    longitude = response.postalcodes[0].lng;

                }

     });
});
```

Can I just not use this api anymore until they get the certificate or is there a way around it?

Comment: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is a DNS resolution problem. Why do you think that is related to HTTPS certificates?

Comment: @vcsjones reading through different posts through a google search and that's what most people were referencing. And I got this on safari:
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.geonames.org” which could put your confidential information at risk. (postalCodeLookupJSON, line 0)

Comment: I *do* get an HTTPS issue when I remove the `www` from the URL you included. The problem is their HTTPS certificate uses SHA1, which is not allowed after 2017. They need to fix their HTTPS certificate.

Comment: What vcsjones said. but anyways at least one of your problem is that www.api.geonames.org doesn't exist; remove that unneeded "www.":)

Comment: @Iskar tried removing www and still same error.

Comment: @vcsjones so no way to use their api correct? Going to have use another service?

Comment: If you're determined you could proxy the request to your server; having the proxy ignoring cert error and passing through the connection. So the clients would connect to your server instead of directly to geonames.